# Neo4j and Cypher - strange behaviour of OPTIONAL MATCH

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Today I was writing DELETE query for some parts of my graph but I am having some problems with `OPTIONAL MATCH`.

Firstly here are example graphs:

http://console.neo4j.org/r/micnvv

and

http://console.neo4j.org/?id=og6d9s

I wanted to write a query that deletes all `foo` and `bar` instances, problem is that sometimes `fooParent` will not exists and also there are cases when single `foo` will not be connected to any `bar`. Because of those conditions I decided to match `fooParent` and `bar` nodes in `OPTIONAL MATCH` query.

Now in first graph (where `fooParent` and `bar` nodes are present) everything I want is matched (`foo1` and all `bar` nodes) using

```
MATCH (foo:Foo { customId: '1' })
OPTIONAL MATCH foo -[rel]-> bar,(fooParent: FooParent)-[fooParentRel]-> foo
RETURN foo, bar
```

In the second graph I have a situation where `fooParent` for given `foo` does not exists and the same query does not match `bar` nodes - only `foo` is matched as you can see.

I was thinking that `OPTIONAL MATCH` is the way to go in case such as mine but it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well yes, because an `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause either

- *completely* matches, in which case it will return the matching rows with every identifier bound, or
- it will *not completely* match, in which case it will return a single row with any unbound identifiers set to `null`.

In this case, your `OPTIONAL MATCH` contains two parts: it tries to match `Foo` nodes that have outgoing relationships (to some bar) *and* incoming relationships to a `FooParent`.

The solution is to split up the `OPTIONAL MATCH`:

```
MATCH (foo:Foo { customId: '1' })
OPTIONAL MATCH foo -[rel]-> bar
OPTIONAL MATCH (fooParent: FooParent)-[fooParentRel]-> foo
RETURN foo, bar
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I didn't know that you can put two `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses, maybe I was a bit fooled by the syntax of refcard: http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/ suggesting that there can be only one `MATCH`/`OPTIONAL MATCH` (no `*` or `+`)

Answer (score 3):

In the second graph, by running two distinct optional match functions the following query will work

```
MATCH (foo:Foo { customId: '1' })

OPTIONAL

MATCH (foo)-[r]->(bar)

OPTIONAL

MATCH (fooParent:fooParent)-[fooParentRel]->(foo2)

RETURN foo, bar, foo2
```

Cheers,

Chris